# Sending NSData to peers with MultiPeer framework

Tags: ios, swift

I have successfully implemented the multiPeer framework into my app and can easily pass images and strings to other devices. My problem is when I try to pass an NSArray converted to NSData.  When the multipeer didReceiveData data func is called i always the following crash:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive

So heres how I send the data:

```
   var myNSData: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(arrayOfNumbers)


        var error : NSError?

        self.session.sendData(myNSData, toPeers: self.session.connectedPeers,
            withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable, error: &error)

        if error != nil {
            print("Error sending data: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

this is how I have tried to recieve the data:

```
    func session(session: MCSession!, didReceiveData data: NSData!,
    fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!)  {
        // Called when a peer sends an NSData to us

        // This needs to run on the main queue
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

  // can't convert data back NSArray without crash 
      var receivedArray:NSArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! NSArray
```

Comment: How is arrayOfNumbers declared? What does myNSData look like before the call to sendData?

Comment: What does arrayOfNumbers contain? Do all elements implement NSCoding? Is the data different when you send it from when you receive it?

Comment: @Dan the arrayOfNumbers is a simple NSArray of Ints as follows:  arrayOfNumbers = [1,3,5,7,8] . This NSArray is declared as follows:    var arrayOfNumbers:NSArray = []

Comment: @Valentin the arrayOfNumbers contains Ints. I have tested the array before sendData is called and the array Nsdata converted back to a new array works fine. But it crashes if read within  didReceieveData func. Do I need to implement NSCoding ? not sure how

Comment: Ive tried saving Strings to the array instead of Ints but I still get the same crash report as above when the data is read within didRecieveData func

Comment: Int doesn't implement NSCoding. Try using NSNumbers instead and check out the result.

Comment: It's true that you haven't provided all the relevant code needed to ascertain the problem; however, I can say this: (1) your approach with respect to using an array makes no sense. I can provide the perfect image-broadcasting code, if you'd like; and, (2) try encoding the array using NSValue, and then archiving the NSValue object.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that you haven't provided all the relevant code needed to ascertain the problem; however, I can say this: (1) your approach with respect to using an array makes no sense. I can provide the perfect image-broadcasting code, if you'd like; and, (2) try encoding the array using NSValue, and then archiving the NSValue object.

It's true that you haven't provided all the relevant code needed to ascertain the problem; however, I can say this: (1) your approach with respect to using an array makes no sense. I've provided you with the perfect image-broadcasting code below; and, (2) try encoding the array using NSValue, and then archiving the NSValue object.

Here's the best way to do it:

On the iOS device sending the image data:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);


    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:newImage scale:1 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    CGImageRelease(newImage);
    CGContextRelease(newContext);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    if (image) {
        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7);
        NSError *err;
        [((ViewController *)self.parentViewController).session sendData:data toPeers:((ViewController *)self.parentViewController).session.connectedPeers withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:&err];
    }
}
```

On the iOS device receiving the image data:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t length;
    void *data;
} ImageCacheDataStruct;

- (void)session:(nonnull MCSession *)session didReceiveData:(nonnull NSData *)data fromPeer:(nonnull MCPeerID *)peerID
{
  dispatch_async(self.imageCacheDataQueue, ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        const void *dataBuffer = [data bytes];
        size_t dataLength = [data length];
        ImageCacheDataStruct *imageCacheDataStruct = calloc(1, sizeof(imageCacheDataStruct));
        imageCacheDataStruct->data = (void*)dataBuffer;
        imageCacheDataStruct->length = dataLength;

        __block const void * kMyKey;
        dispatch_queue_set_specific(self.imageDisplayQueue, &kMyKey, (void *)imageCacheDataStruct, NULL);

        dispatch_sync(self.imageDisplayQueue, ^{
            ImageCacheDataStruct *imageCacheDataStruct = calloc(1, sizeof(imageCacheDataStruct));
            imageCacheDataStruct = dispatch_queue_get_specific(self.imageDisplayQueue, &kMyKey);
            const void *dataBytes = imageCacheDataStruct->data;
            size_t length = imageCacheDataStruct->length;
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:dataBytes length:length];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            if (image) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [((ViewerViewController *)self.childViewControllers.lastObject).view.layer setContents:(__bridge id)image.CGImage];
                    dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The reason for the semaphores and the separate GCD queues is simple: you want the frames to display at equal time intervals. Otherwise, the video will seem to slow down at first at times, right before speeding up way past normal in order to catch up. My scheme ensures that each frame plays one after another at the same pace, regardless of network bandwidth bottlenecks.